# Distributing marbles into buckets for maximal colour sharing

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, np-complete

i've got a problem that feels very much like it's NP-hard but I would love some help proving it primarily.

Secondary to that, if an optimal polynomal time algorithm can be proposed that is even better, although even good "greedy" approximations are fine.

Given $M$ marbles, $B$ buckets and each bucket having capacity $K$, where $M = BK$ , find some distribution of the marbles that maximizes the number of colours that are shared. colour $A$ and colour $B$ are considered to be shared if they appear together in the same bucket.

The distribution of colours is known for a given problem, and can be sorted and added in any order you desire. We can define a distribution as follows:

$m_1 + m_2 + m_3 + \dots + m_n = M = BK$

where $n$ is the the number of colours. We also have $0 < m_k \le M = BK$ for some $k$th colour

Example:

| BucketId | Colours |
| --- | --- |
| $0$ | $A, C$ |
| $1$ | $A, C$ |
| $2$ | $B, D$ |
| $3$ | $B, D$ |

$M = 8, B = 4, K = 2
\\m_1 = 2, m_2 = 2, m_3 = 2, m_4 = 2$

Clearly, this is non-optimal since we may swap $C$ in bucket 1, with $D$ in bucket 2 and achieve a better outcome (more colours shared).

Any insight into this problem would be infinitely appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: Two questions (even though this is not at all my area and I will probably have no insight into your actual question!): 1. Do you mean to say “... with $\color{red}A$ in bucket 2...”? Swapping $B$ in bucket 1 with $\color{red}C$ in bucket 2 doesn’t change the collection of bucket contents at all, just the ordering. 2. Instead of “maximizes the number of colours that are shared,” do you maybe mean “maximizes the number of pairs of colours that are shared”? Your table shows all three colours being shared, but there is a swap that would raise the number of shared color pairs from two to three. 2.

Comment: @SteveKass nope you are right haha, I had some idea of an example in my mind, but wrote something different. I modified the example so it should be more clear. C never shares with B and D never shares with A until after the swap

Comment: Your edit addresses my first point, but I think “number of colours shared” (call it $N(f)$, where $f$ is the assignment of balls to buckets) needs to be more well-defined. In your table, how many colors are shared? (Looks like $N(f)=4$ for both assignments. Color $A$ is shared, $B$ is shared, $C$ is shared, and color $D$ is shared.)? If you got “more colours shared” with a swap, then shouldn’t $N(f)$ have increased? Do you mean more “pairs of colors” shared? (For bigger $M,B,K$ maybe you mean more *subsets* of colors shared, or who knows what. I feel like there’s a hypergraph hiding here.)

Comment: Yes, apologies. Its basically maximizing the number of pairs which are shared. So by swaping B and C in my table we go from:
A C, B D to A C , A D, B C, B D (2 more pairs)

Comment: @MikeEarnest yes this is correct, I will try edit the post shortly to wrote exactly what you have here. The number of each colour is not guaranteed to be indentical

Comment: I have just edited both the explanation and the example to be more clear on the colour distribution

Comment: Problem could also be interpretted as: maximize the number of edges in the union of $B$ number of $K$-complete subgraphs (that can be chosen) of the $n$-complete graph. With some wording to account for the constraint of given distribution of colors and the possibility of multiple balls of same color in the same bucket.

Comment: This actually did cross my mind too @TonyMathew and was able to find out choosing a minimal complete subgraph in a complete subgraph is NP-hard (if I tried to perhaps do it this way). Unfortunately this also doesn't say anything about the problem and where it is in P/NP , just hints that it might be NP-hard.

Comment: When $K=2$, this is polynomial by reduction to a b-matching problem

Answer (score 2):

Here's an integer linear programming formulation.  Let nonnegative integer decision variable $x_{kb}$ be the number of marbles of color $k$ assigned to bucket $b$.  Let binary decision variable $y_{k\ell}$ indicate whether color pair $(k,\ell)$ is ever shared.  Let binary decision variable $z_{k\ell b}$ indicate whether color pair $(k,\ell)$ is shared in bucket $b$.  The problem is to maximize $$\sum_{1 \le k<\ell\le n} y_{k\ell}$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_b x_{kb} &= m_k &&\text{for all colors $k$} \tag1\label1\\
\sum_k x_{kb} &= K &&\text{for all buckets $b$} \tag2\label2\\
y_{k\ell} &\le \sum_b z_{k\ell b} &&\text{for all $k<\ell$} \tag3\label3\\
z_{k\ell b} &\le x_{kb} &&\text{for all $k<\ell$ and all $b$} \tag4\label4\\
z_{k\ell b} &\le x_{\ell b} &&\text{for all $k<\ell$ and all $b$} \tag5\label5
\end{align}

Constraint \eqref{1} assigns each marble to a bucket.
Constraint \eqref{2} assigns $K$ marbles to each bucket.
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces a shared pair to be shared in at least one bucket.
Constraints \eqref{4} and \eqref{5} force at least one marble of each color for each shared pair.

For your first example, the maximum is $4$ shared pairs, achieved by
the following $x_{kb}$:
\begin{matrix}
k \backslash b &0 &1 &2 &3 \\
\hline
A &1 &1 &0 &0 \\
B &1 &0 &0 &1 \\
C &0 &0 &1 &1 \\
D &0 &1 &1 &0 \\
\end{matrix}

For your second example, the maximum is $5$ shared pairs, achieved by the following $x_{kb}$:
\begin{matrix}
k \backslash b &0 &1 &2 &3 &4 \\
\hline
A &1 &0 &1 &1 &0 \\
B &0 &1 &0 &0 &1 \\
C &0 &1 &1 &0 &0 \\
D &0 &0 &0 &1 &1 \\
E &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: It's a neat observation to me that the perspective has flipped when formulating the MILP. Naturally, one would go about the problem  as first choosing the bucket distribution then counting the shared pairs. But here we're starting with the shared pairs, and forcing the distribution to be valid and satisfy our desired shared pairs.

Comment: Not too familiar with linear programming but I will certainly look into later. Looks like a good formulation

Answer (score 1):

Thought I might answer my own question, as to the best hueristic I have found so far. Certainly is not optimal, and I still haven't found any way to reason whether this problem is NP-hard or not.

This just seems to be an approach that is consistently giving close to optimum. I have not been able to prove an approximation ratio either though. The algorithm in itself is very simple, and has out-performed other more complicated ones I have tried.

Start by ordering all $n$ colours such that $m_k \ge m_{k+1}$

I now take each marble in the list and add it to the bucket with the fewest marbles. Taking the lower indexed bucket in a tie-breaker scenario. This is effectively doing some round-robin across the buckets. This might give us something like

| BucketId | Colours |
| --- | --- |
| $0$ | $A, C$ |
| $1$ | $A, C$ |
| $2$ | $A, D$ |
| $3$ | $B, D$ |
| $4$ | $B, E$ |

$M = 10, B = 5, K = 2
\\m_1 = 3, m_2 = 2, m_3 = 2, m_4 = 2, m_5 = 1$

The idea now is simple, for each entry in the table, where $B_i \ne B_j$ (colours in different buckets): We swap them, if more colours are shared, we have achieved a better table. Save this table and repeat the process. If they do not increase sharing, revert the swap, and try a different valid pairing.

Keep doing so until no more colours may be shared. An example swap above might produce:

| BucketId | Colours |
| --- | --- |
| $0$ | $A, E$ |
| $1$ | $A, C$ |
| $2$ | $A, D$ |
| $3$ | $B, D$ |
| $4$ | $B, C$ |

Which takes us from 4 colours shared to 5